# Does it make sense to use init-only setters on request models in an ASP.NET Core application to avoid mutation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, immutability, .net-5, c#-9.0

I've seen developers mutating request models in controller actions like this:

```
public class ProfileController
{
  private const string DefaultCulture = "en-US";

  public Task SaveProfile(string culture, ProfileModel profile)
  {
    profile.Culture = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture) ? DefaultCulture : culture;

    // then profile is passed to a service/repository to be saved to the DB
  }
}
```

Not sure why it was done that way, but I would like to avoid mutating request models. So, I'm thinking of using init-only setters on all request models to make them immutable and force developers to map to a domain model:

```
public class ProfileController
{
  private const string DefaultCulture = "en-US";

  public Task SaveProfile(string culture, ProfileModel profile)
  {
    var profileDomain = new ProfileDomain
    {
      Culture = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture) ? DefaultCulture : culture;
    };
    
    // This will cause a compile error when ProfileModel.Culture becomes init-only
    // profile.Culture = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture) ? DefaultCulture : culture;
  }
}
```

Are there any drawback or risks that I should consider if I change all request models to init-only setters?

Comment: "Not sure why it was done that way" - people do it that way because that's how the official documentation and examples/samples do it, even though we all know it's a bad idea if you're a fan of FP-style :(

Comment: "`init`-only setters on all request models to make them immutable" - I am not a fan of `init`-only setters (as opposed to constructor parameters) because there's no guarantees that a property will ever actually be set to a meaningful value and/or ensuring the class's state invariants are correct. Unfortunately ASP.NET Core's Form data model-binder doesn't support populating objects through constructor parameters.

Comment: Ctor params? That will not work on a request model. Deserialization will fail in this case. EDIT: Ok, I just saw your edit.

Comment: There is backwards compatibility, however that can be worked around. In short there is not much that can go wrong if you want relatively immutable classes and cant use the constructor. However what can you do? to a large degree this is what company policy and code review is for.

Comment: "because there's no guarantees that a property will ever actually be set to a meaningful value" - for request models, we can rely on model state validation in this case. But this is a very good point. Thanks!